# Visual Studio Code - launch parameter for node app being surrounded by double quotes

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm having some problems putting a parameter for launching (debugging) a node app from Visual Studio Code. I'm using this config at launch.json:

```
// Command line arguments passed to the program.
"args": [
    "-cache-dig cache"
]
```

and when launching VS Code surrounds the parameter with double quotes:

node foo.js "-cache-dig cache"

...which is not accepted by this app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `args` key in your launch configuration to put each command line argument in a separate element.

For example:

```
"args": [
    "-cache-dig",
    "cache"
]
```

The reason being that while `-cache-dig cache` is a single option at the application level, it is actually composed of two separate command line arguments (a name `-cache-dig` and a value `cache`).